# NotificationCenter swift3 Can't observe post

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

I have 3 notifications:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name("Notification1"), object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name("Notification2"), object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name("Notification3"), object: nil)
```

And I have for each post one differents observer in view controller

**First**:`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:NSNotification.Name("Notification1"), object: nil, queue: nil, using: updateUx)`

**Second**:`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:NSNotification.Name("Notification2"), object: nil, queue: nil, using: updateUx)`

**Third**:`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:NSNotification.Name("Notification3"), object: nil, queue: nil, using: updateUx)`

updateUx func contain only a print of notification.

I only got my first notification I cannot catch the two other, I don't know why.

Comment: There's no way your first notification can be received. You are not observing to `Notification1`, but you are observing `DashboardNotification `

Comment: are you sure the names are to add observer and post observer are same ?

Comment: Try changing `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` like following. It should work. I tried it and it does.

Comment: Sorry my bad, for posting this on github, I change the name, I edit my question.

Comment: I am not facing any issue while using this code. Are you sure your observers are added and then notification is posted ?

Comment: Check updated answer. If this doesn't work, I don't know what would. :)

Comment: Where you remove observer? If you remove observer in viewWillDisappear, controller which currently not on screen will not receive any notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your observers like following:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUx), name: NSNotification.Name("Notification1"), object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUx), name: NSNotification.Name("Notification2"), object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUx), name: NSNotification.Name("Notification3"), object: nil)
```

And you are good to go.

---

**EDIT:** Full source code (This project has a `UIButton` on view and the `@IBAction` is connected to it in storyboard. On tapping that button, all 3 notifications will get posted. The log is supposed to get printed thrice in console)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUx), name: NSNotification.Name("Notification1"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUx), name: NSNotification.Name("Notification2"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUx), name: NSNotification.Name("Notification3"), object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @IBAction func abc (_ sender: UIButton) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name("Notification1"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name("Notification2"), object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name("Notification3"), object: nil)
    }

    func updateUx(){
        print("received...")
    }
}
```