# how can I use function waiting to get something in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, listener, wait

I want to use a method that wait for getting some thing and then do some thing else - I have a progressive in my app and want to use a function that waiting for progressive to be 100 percent and then that function execute - in generally I want to know how can I use a method that execute when another things happens - I used group method many times but this is more different(its some thing like listener)

```
let myGroup = DispatchGroup()

myGroup.enter()
//// Do your task
//// When you task complete
myGroup.leave()
myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {              
////// do your remaining work         
}
```

Comment: Why not post a `Notification` when the "thing" happens?

Comment: can you write simple codes for notification here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `notification`, `delegate` or `blocks` to do that. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792213/7456236) answer for delegates. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42436912/7456236) is an example for notifications. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41745562/7456236) answer contains how to use completion handler blocks They are explained in details here.

**I am updating this with delegate example :**

```
//Do this in the class (assuming it as EventViewController) where event occurs


    protocol delegateForEvent {
    func didEventCompleted()
     }

class EventViewController: UIViewController {
var delegate:delegateForEvent!
```

When the event completed, call this

```
self.delegate.didEventCompleted()   // call this at the time of color change
```

And in ViewController or whichever class you want to receive the event (assuming it as ViewController.swift),

In **ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, delegateForEvent {  // Set delegateForEvent in interface
```

set the delegate where you create your eventViewController instance in viewController.swift

```
myEventViewController.delegate = self;   // set it where you created your object
```

and add the delegate function in **viewController.swift**

```
didEventCompleted{
   //here you can do whatever you want to after the event completion
}
```

Comment: I read this links can you write more simple codes here please?

Comment: thanks a lot can I use this method for two view controllers ? I mean in first one some functions are running and in the second one when the functions in the first one finished do some thing else?

Comment: Yes, that is the basic purpose of delegates.